# Should a Sheep Dip Machine use encrypted hard drive?

Tags: usb, hard-drive, encryption, security, malware

Building a virus scanning / malware machine using clamvirus docker container for my organization. The machine is known as a sheep dip machine. Would encrypting the hard drive give me any security benefits?

The plan is to scan USB/CD-ROM devices. The devices would be shared with a container that would be updated hourly with virus definitions only if no usb/cd-rom is detected.

So, back to my question. Would you recommend encrypting the hard drive just in case of a virus or malware that escapes a docker container?

Comment: This quersion isn't really related to Ubuntu in particular and would be better fit over on [Security.SE].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drive encryption is designed to protect your data if someone gains physical access to your computer or hard drive. It's not designed to and will not protect from malware running on the computer, since decryption keys are in memory and all encrypted data is accessible while the computer is running.